# Given a cartesian equation of a plane , how can find the equation of a rotated plane

Tags: math, rotation, cartesian

I want to rotate a plane represented by the equation z = 6 , by n degrees along y axis and find the new equation of the plane. how can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: do you want a mathematical solution or programming solution

Comment: Ideally a programming solution.

Comment: do you have the mathematical procedure for the same?

Comment: Before you can program this, you will need to understand the mathematics behind it.  Therefore, I suggest you do a Google search for "rotation matrix" or "quaternion rotation".  There are some very readable articles over on Wikipedia on these subjects.

Comment: Nope like to see it applied , read Wikipedia . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base point (0,0,6) after rotation will lie in XZ plane with coordinates

`(x0, y0, z0) = (-6*sin(Fi), 0, 6*cos(Fi))`

normal vector

**n** `= (A,B,C) = (-sin(Fi), 0, cos(Fi))`

so new plane equation is ([for explanation see beginning of the article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane.html))

```
A*(x-x0)+B*(y-y0)+C*(z-z0)=0
or
-sin(Fi)*x + cos(Fi)*z - 6 = 0
```

Comment: By base point do you mean the center of the plane ? Is there any reference you can point me to to understand your answer? How will the base point be in xz plane?

Comment: Base point is any point in plane. I chose intersection of plane with Z-axis as initial base point, then rotated it. About rotation - read about affine transformations. About plane defining - link added to the answer.

Comment: Hi MBo , A bit confused about this (xo,y0,z0) should be (6sin(fi),0,6cps(fi) ) given rotation matrix around y of ([cos(fi),0,sin(fi))],[0,1,0],[-sin(fi), 0 , cos(fi)]). Is that correct? the extra -ve for x should not be there?

Comment: vector (0,0,6) multiplied by matrix you described - gives (-6*sin(Fi), 0, 6*cos(Fi) vector

Comment: Not if (0,0,6) is a colum vector?

Comment: V is row vector when V*M multiplication order is used

Comment: ok got you ! last one how did you get the normal vector from (x0,y0,z0)?

Comment: normal vector is independent from base point.

Comment: Hi Sorry  I meant from (Xo , Y0, z0 ) in your answer how did you derive normal to be ( -sin(Fi) , 0 , cos(fi) )

Comment: @MBo What would happen if the plane is also translated?  Should we add the translations to the base point? Say is we had Translation `(-5,1,-3)` should we do something like `base_point = (x0-5,y0+1,z0-3)`. If this is true the equation of the plane should be `new_norm*(R-new_base_point)=6`. `R=(x,y,z)`

Comment: @Alexander Cska If translation goes after rotation - yes, you are right

Comment: @MBo and what about the opposite order?

Comment: @Alexander Cska Base point will have another coordinates

Comment: @MBo I Have an equation of a plane x=9. Then I try to run 3D translation and rotation on the point (9,0,0). However I am not able to get the correct position, unless I do only translation. Say I can translate the origin, but any other point involving translation and rotation fails.

Comment: @Alexander Cska What is translation vector? How is rotation defined?

Comment: @MBo I have a plane say x=6. The rotation is clockwise -30 degrees. I accomplish this via two steps with numpy     `n2=R.dot(np.array(n0))`  `pfin= np.array(p0) + np.array(Tr) + n2*dx`. `n0` is the original normal, `p0` the base pint and `Tr` is the translation by which i change the base point

Comment: @Alexander Cska Too much for comments. If you will create a question, describe rotation better - I did not catch.